# Error when removing contentEditable attribute using JQuery in FF and Opera, works in Chrome

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have problem with this piece of code:

```
var el = $('div#editor');
el.find('*[contentEditable]').removeAttr('contentEditable');
```

It works great in Chrome 4/5/6, but it doesn't work in FF (3.6.) or Opera (10.60).

In FF it throws this exception:

Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "http://www.www.com/js/script.js Line: 51"]

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening and how to fix it ?

Right now I am using this fix, but it's not clean solution, because it leaves contentEditable attribute and I have to clean it up on server side:

```
try {  
  el.find('*[contentEditable]').removeAttr('contentEditable');
} catch (e) {
  el.find('*[contentEditable]').attr('contentEditable', false);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, while you're here, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine to me...

## html

```
<div contenteditable="true">testing....</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$('[contenteditable]').removeAttr('contenteditable');
```

maybe try all small letters on `contenteditable` and remove `*` on `$('*[contenteditable]')`

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R3ByA/)

tested on  FF (3.6.) or Opera (10.10).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I feel little stupid, because I've tried a lot of things, except your simple solution. Now it works as it should. 
Also thanks for posting demo - it seems I have discovered useful tool for testing - jsfiddle.net.